# Permission issue with VSCode and WSL (code: command not found)

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am new to WSL and have installed VS code natively on Windows 10 with the installer. Currently, when I try to run VS Code command `code` from WSL, I receive the following message:

`bash: /mnt/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code: Permission denied`

Also, when I try to run VS Code Server for WSL, I am getting a similar message.

```
[2020-06-29 17:41:41.640] Launching C:\windows\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu sh -c '"$VSCODE_WSL_EXT_LOCATION/scripts/wslServer.sh" cd9ea6488829f560dc949a8b2fb789f3cdc05f5d stable .vscode-server 0  ' in c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.44.4}
[2020-06-29 17:41:41.779] sh: 1: /mnt/c/Users/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.44.4/scripts/wslServer.sh: Permission denied
[2020-06-29 17:41:41.780] VS Code Server for WSL closed unexpectedly.
```

I have tried configuring the permissions for wsl @ `wsl.conf`:

```
[automount]
enabled = true
options = "uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022,fmask=11,metadata"
```

Not sure if this is relevant, but I am able to run `code` from Windows Powershell.

I am currently using `Microsoft Windows 1909 (OS Build 18363.836)` with `WSL v1`.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Run wsl.exe or PowerShell as an Administrator [Runs as Admin Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYEsR.png)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

None of the previous answers worked for me. Instead after a lot of trial and error, I discovered that the `code.exe` was set in a way that it was being run as *Administrator*. This is what prevented it from running in the WSL. Find the VC Code executable, and ensure it doesn't have the admin *Shield* on it's icon.

Comment: My problem, and solution!

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with your /etc/wsl.conf. Change the contents of the file to:

```
[automount]
enabled=true
root = /
options="metadata,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=002,dmask=002,fmask=002"
```

umask,dmask, and fmask all have to do with permissions. A pretty good explanation of them can be found here : [https://askubuntu.com/questions/429848/dmask-and-fmask-mount-options#:~:text=fmask%20and%20dmask%20are%20mount,files%20and%20dmask%20to%20directories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429848/dmask-and-fmask-mount-options#:%7E:text=fmask%20and%20dmask%20are%20mount,files%20and%20dmask%20to%20directories)

Comment: I do not have this file on my wsl installation

Answer (score 2):

After removing the folder `~/.vscode-server` the command `code .` worked again.

```
$ sudo rm -R ~/.vscode-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution that worked for me was described here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90164

fixed by setting remote.WSL.fileWatcher.polling in VSCode settings to True

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for someone will helpfull...
For example i have mistake like this:

$ code .
/c/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code: line 61: /c/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe: Permission denied

My error resolving was by click right button mouse on icon VS Code and chosen settings then "compatibility" tab and finaly disabled "run the program as an administrator"

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting my Ubuntu user in the www-data group. I edited the /etc/group. That www-data group is the one in my configuration belongs to Apache2. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your files/directory does not have the right permissions. Run the following command:

```
sudo chmod 666 -R ./
```

This command will let other users (other than root) read/write to the files. `-R` is for recursive. This will modify all the files/folders inside that directory with new permisssions. You can run `ls -l` command to see the current permissions and the ones after ruuning the command.